# Angularjs ui.bootstrap Accordion

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I found this accordion effect which works very nicely: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

But I need the accordion to open differently, so that the content of each accordion-group appears above the accordion-header that opens it.  Just wondering if anyone knows a simple way to accomplish this or if I'll have to make my own custom accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIBootstrap accordion does not support having the panel content above the title by default.

Below is the `accordion-group.html` template, which is the HTML for each panel. As you can see there is currently no logic to cover your use case.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading"><span ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
      <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion-group.html

However, it should be fairly simply to modify this file to have the title below the content. Simply change this template to have the `divs` in the order you prefer.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-collapse" collapse="!isOpen">
      <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading"><span ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest taking a fork of the repository on GitHub, so you can make your changes without losing the benefits of version control. http://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap